# In Python, how to know whether a string contain a jump substring. like 'abcd' contain 'ad'

Tags: python, string, nlp

In Python, how to know whether a string contain a jump substring. like 'abcd' contain 'ad'
'I very like play basketball' contain 'like basketball'

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an iterator from the test string and validate that every character in the subsequence can be found in the sequence of characters generated by the iterator:

```
def is_subsequence(a, b):
    seq = iter(b)
    return all(i in seq for i in a)
```

so that:

```
print(is_subsequence('ad', 'abcd'))
print(is_subsequence('adc', 'abcd'))
```

outputs:

```
True
False
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/jGdpis